# how to see if a member has left from a telegram channel?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I want to develope a bot in telegram to set as the admin of my channel.
And I want it to notify me whenever a member leaves the channel. And I want it to tell me who it was. and I prefer to have name or username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can only get [member count](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmemberscount) at this time, even your bot is admin, can't get full list of member, you can just clumsy [track users](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember) by their ID.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can. If you can see all subscribers in your channel and you can make a program to identify who lives your channel by checking and substracting existing members vs last members & you can set activity starter when member counts change

@fkadeal this is my idea & it's not tested yet